# Solving ODE using `NDSolve`ProcessEquations` in an iterative fashion

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve the following ODE using `NDSolveProcessEquations` but in an iterative way.

$\ddot{x}(t)+5\dot{x}(t)+3x(t)=2\cos(2\pi t)$

$\dot{x}(0)=0,\,x(0)=1$

I wrote the below code

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
    (*----------------------------------------------------------*)  
    dxdt0 = 0; x0 = 1; 
    ti = 0; tf = 10; \[Delta]t = 0.01; 
    ItrNo = Round[(tf - ti)/\[Delta]t]; acc = 12; 
    eq1 = Derivative[2][x][t] + 5*Derivative[1][x][t] + 3*x[t] == 2*Cos[2*Pi*t]; 
    ics = {Derivative[1][x][0] == dxdt0, x[0] == x0}; 
    (*----------------------------------------------------------*)  
    StateVar = First[NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{eq1, ics},{Derivative[1][x], x}, t, MaxSteps -> Infinity,PrecisionGoal -> acc, AccuracyGoal -> acc]]; 
    solC = ConstantArray[0, ItrNo - 1];
(*----------------------------------------------------------*)   
    Do[ics = {Derivative[1][x][0] == dxdt0, x[0] == x0}; 
        NewStateVar = First[NDSolve`Reinitialize[StateVar,ics]]; 
        NDSolve`Iterate[NewStateVar, \[Delta]t]; 
        solUC = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[NewStateVar]; 
        x0 = x[t] /. {t -> \[Delta]t} /. solUC; 
        dxdt0 = Derivative[1][x][t] /. {t -> \[Delta]t} /. solUC; 
        solC[[i]] = Flatten[{dxdt0, x0}]; 
        If[Mod[Rationalize[\[Delta]t]*i, Rationalize[1]] == 0, 
        Print["  t = ", \[Delta]t*i]], {i, ItrNo - 1}]
```

The plots were generated using

```
tData = Table[n, {n, \[Delta]t, tf - \[Delta]t, \[Delta]t}]; 
xData = solC[[All, 2]]; 
dxdtData = solC[[All, 1]]; 
xList = Partition[Riffle[tData, xData], 2]; 
dxdtList = Partition[Riffle[tData, dxdtData], 2]; 
ListLinePlot[{xList, dxdtList}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]]
```

And I got some results

[image]

To validate the result I checked with `DSolve` and `NDSolve` and instantly understood that they had produced the correct result, which obviously different from what `NDSolveProcessEquations` had produced.

```
 ClearAll["Global`*"]
   dxdt0 = 0; x0 = 1; 
    eq = Derivative[2][x][t] + 5*Derivative[1][x][t] + 3*x[t] == 
       2*Cos[2*Pi*t]; 
    Ics = {Derivative[1][x][0] == dxdt0, x[0] == x0}; 
    sol = First[DSolve[{eq, Ics}, x[t], t]]; 
    y[t] = D[x[t] /. sol, t]; 
    Plot[{y[t], x[t] /. sol}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
       FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]]
```

[image]

```
sol1 = First[
   NDSolve[{eq, Ics}, {Derivative[1][x][t], x[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]]; 
Plot[{Derivative[1][x][t] /. sol1, x[t] /. sol1}, {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
   Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]]
```

[image]

What I have understood is that the term $2\cos(2\pi t)$ (where time $t$ appears explicitly ) is the main reason for two different results. In my code I have failed to incorporate the fact that with every iteration, time $t$ grows and this changes the value of function $2\cos(2\pi t)$ at every iteration steps. I did not also want to include `NDSolveProcessEquations` within the loop.

Looking forward for any valuable help.

Comment: Why not skip reinitialization and use `NDSolve`Iterate[StateVar, \[Delta]t * i]` at each step?

Comment: Actually, in a separate problem, I need to correct state variables, (i.e., x and dxdt) at each integration step, using some correction formula. That corrected state variables are being fed as new initial conditions at next integration step. That is why I reinitialize the state variables at each step.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It also did not work. The solutions became straight lines only.

Comment: I got [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/moMA8.png), which seems to have the derivative and x switched from your images.  Sounds like you plugged in the same `t` at each step instead of `dt * i`.  Your description of what's wrong suggests this immediately:  At each step put the IC at the last `t` and iterate to `t + dt`.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get where to incorporate that in the code. Should I write the ICs (inside the loop) like `ics={[x]'[dt*i] == dxdt0, x[dt*i] == x0}`? If you could provide the revised code, it will be helpful. Also, in your image isn't the blue line (state variable x) supposed to start from 1?

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelE2. I have got the correct result.

Comment: @michaelE2 is right. For completeness here's the corrected code (the corrected part has been marked): https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSO6X.png I'm voting to close this question because it's due to a simple mistake.

Comment: @SoumyajitRoy I have a related equation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193429/how-to-save-data-and-show-step-sizes-when-using-components-and-data-structures-o?noredirect=1#comment503576_193429) with `NDSolveProcessEquations` coupled with `NDSolveIterate` and `NDSolveProcessSolutions`.  How to save the `InterpolatingFunction` obtained in order to re-upload and plot it using `Get[...]` when re-opening a notebook? I leave a message here because I don't know how to reach you. Thanks a lot.