# How to save data and show step sizes when using components and data structures of NDSolve?

Tags: plotting, dumpsave

In some applications, it is advantageous to access [components](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html#1284231932) of `NDSolve`.
However, we could also need to observe the step size taken in the numerical integration, as in [Stiffness Detection](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessTest.html#278248124).
For example:

```
{ndssdata} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{D[u[t, x], t] == 
0.1 D[u[t, x], x, x] + u[t, x] D[u[t, x], x], 
u[0, x] == Cos[2 Pi x], u[t, 0] == u[t, 1]}, u, t, {x, 0, 1},
Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"
(*Method\[Rule]"ExplicitRungeKutta"*)]

tm = 1;
NDSolve`Iterate[ndssdata, {0, tm}]
sol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[ndssdata]
```

My questions:

1. How to obtain and plot the step sizes just as using `StepDataPlot[]` with `NDSolve`;
2. How to save the `InterpolatingFunction` u[t,x] in order to upload and plot with it afterward using `Get[...]` and `Plot3D[u[t, x] /. sol...]` after closing and re-opening MMA.

I tried `DumpSave["test.mx", sol]` and `Get["...\\test.mx"]` which gives me

> Get::noopen: Cannot open ...\test.mx. >>
>   $Failed

Please leave your comments and thoughts. Thank you for any suggestions and help.

Comment: Did you already have a look at the code within `NDSolveUtilities.m`? The implementation of `StepDataPlot[]` should be there, which you can modify for your needs.

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive Sorry I haven't. Did you mean the last subsection in _Advanced Numerical Differential Equation Solving_?

Comment: No, I meant for you to look at the file in the location returned by `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "AddOns", "ExtraPackages", "DifferentialEquations", "NDSolveUtilities.m"}]`.

Comment: You can use, `sol >> "D:\\sol_data"` for storing the data at a particular location (say at D, with a file name sol_data, no extension is required.) To get the data back to a variable, you can write `solImport=<<"D:\\sol_data"`. This will work even after closing and reopening Mathematica. To plot the data, use `Plot3D[u[t, x] /. solImport, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}]`.

Answer (score 1):

The step data is stored in the interpolating function:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] == 
     0.1 D[u[t, x], x, x] + u[t, x] D[u[t, x], x], 
    u[0, x] == Cos[2 Pi x], u[t, 0] == u[t, 1]}, 
   u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];

sol["Coordinates"][[1]]
{0.`, 0.06800128840268457`, 0.09489195680748204`, \
0.13502467607112256`, 0.18776999888298834`, 0.2546090610966109`, \
0.33329197483384987`, 0.4236985592366587`, 0.5236985592366588`, \
0.6236985592366587`, 0.7236985592366587`, 0.8236985592366587`, \
0.9236985592366588`, 1.`}
```